# The AM-GM inequality with rational weights

Tags: inequality

This is **Problem 2.2** of Steele's "The Cauchy-Schwarz Master Class":

Suppose that $p_1, \ldots, p_n$ are nonnegative rationals whose sum is $1$. Show that for any real numbers $a_1, \ldots, a_n$, one has:

$$\prod_{k=1}^n a_k ^{p_k} \le \sum_{k=1}^n p_k a_k$$

I understand that we can find an integer $N$ for which there are integers $t_i$'s, such that $p_k = t_k/N$ for each $k$. So that:

$$\prod_{k=1}^n a_k ^{p_k} = \left( \prod_{k=1}^n a_k ^{t_k} \right)^{1/N}$$

Recalling that the AM-GM inequality states:

$$\left( \prod_{k=1}^n a_k \right)^{1/n} \le \frac1{n} \sum_{k=1}^n a_k$$

How can I use it to conclude the required result?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

Pick $t_1$ copies of $a_1$,  $t_2$ copies of $a_2$ , etc. to implement the normal AM-GM inequality i.e. let 
$$b_1 = b_2 = \cdots = b_{t_1} = a_1, \, \, b_{t_1+1} = b_{t_1+2} = \cdots = b_{t_1+t_2} = a_2, \,\,\cdots \,\, b_{t_1+\cdots + t_{n-1}\,+1} = b_{t_1+\cdots + t_{n-1}\,+2} = \cdots = b_{t_1+\cdots + t_{n}} = a_{n}$$
and appply the AM-GM inequality on the $b$s.